# Passing the output of vbYesNoCancel into a batch

Tags: batch-file, vbscript

Good day, I am cuurently writing a batch file for a simple program and I am using VBscript to recieve input from users. At this point in the program I have the question: "Would you like to backup it now?" in a MsgBox. If the user presses yes, it has to go to a tag in the batch called :AUTOBACKUP. For no, it has to goto :REJECTAB. Here is the code I currently have, but it does not work? How could I correct it?

```
 :STARTUPDAS
    ECHO Wscript.echo i=msgbox("The automatic backup function is active. Would you like to backup now?",                  VBYesNoCancel + VBQuestion, "BACKUP")>vbst.vbs&vbst.vbs
    SET _stringb
    ENDLOCAL & SET i=%_stringb%
    cls
    cls
    echo.
    echo.
    echo             The automatic backup function is active.
    echo             Would you like to perform a backup now? Y/N
    echo.
    if i==6 goto AUTOBACKUP
    if i==7 goto REJECTAB
    echo.
    echo Invalid option. Please try again
    echo.
    pause
    :STARTUPDAS
    ECHO Wscript.echo i=msgbox("The automatic backup function is active. Would you like to backup now?",                  VBYesNoCancel + VBQuestion, "BACKUP")>vbst.vbs&vbst.vbs
    SET _stringb
    ENDLOCAL & SET i=%_stringb%
    cls
    cls
    echo.
    echo.
    echo             The automatic backup function is active.
    echo             Would you like to perform a backup now? Y/N
    echo.
    if i==6 goto AUTOBACKUP
    if i==7 goto REJECTAB
    echo.
    echo Invalid option. Please try again
    echo.
    pause
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
@echo off

    call :MsgBox "Should i do something?"  "VBYesNoCancel+VBQuestion" "Just asking"
    if errorlevel 7 (
        echo NO - do nothing
    ) else if errorlevel 6 (
        echo YES - do something
    ) else if errorlevel 2 (
        echo CANCEL - do .....
    )

    exit /b

:MsgBox prompt type title
    setlocal enableextensions
    set "tempFile=%temp%\%~nx0.%random%%random%%random%vbs.tmp"
    >"%tempFile%" echo(WScript.Quit msgBox("%~1",%~2,"%~3") & cscript //nologo //e:vbscript "%tempFile%"
    set "exitCode=%errorlevel%" & del "%tempFile%" >nul 2>nul
    endlocal & exit /b %exitCode%
```

For a simple MsgBox, it is better to use `WScript.Quit` to return as an errorlevel the result of the MsgBox function