# I need help using VBScript to control a commandline program

Tags: windows, batch-file, vbscript

Using a VBScript (just an example) something like

```
result = MsgBox ("Would you like to install the AntrixAPI?", vbYesNo, "Installing AntrixAPI")

Select Case result
Case vbYes
MsgBox("The API will be installed.")
Case vbNo
MsgBox("The API will not be install.")
End Select
```

How could I use this to control a commandline program. Let's say the user selected yes. Then the command would go to a certain point only if the user selected yes. 
(example command)

```
@echo off
:UserSelectedYes
REM This is where the prompt would go if the user selected yes
wget http://www.example.com/thisisafakedomain/api/antrix
:UserSelectedNo
REM This is where the prompt would go if the user selected no
end
```

Would this be possible?

Comment: You can try [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21575421/2861476)

Comment: This is exactly what I wanted. 100% thank you SOOO much

Comment: possible duplicate of [Passing the output of vbYesNoCancel into a batch](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21574341/passing-the-output-of-vbyesnocancel-into-a-batch)

Answer (score 0):

You can create a MS-DOS process and execute every script, you want!

Just like this:

```
Dim oProcess As New Process
With (oProcess.StartInfo)
   .Arguments = "/k <command> & <command> & <command> & exit"
    .FileName = "cmd.exe"
    .WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden
    .CreateNoWindow = True
End With
oProcess.Start()
```

It is not the best and genteelst way, but the fastest.
I do not know exactly, if this is what you wanted. So feel free to redefine your question, it was not very clear what you were asking for!

Comment: This is kinda what I wanted. Let's say I have an MS-DOS command, that calls a file `script.vbs`. This file prompts the user with a yes/no box. If the user selects the `yes` option, then the `script.vbs` will go to the same .bat/.cmd program that called the `script.vbs` and will go to a certain label and only run that one label.

Comment: Oh, you wanna use vbs? (i thought you mean VB) That's a problem, because, vbs is not able to use the Process class. Well, your problem becomes more complicated. Why don't you ask the user, what he wants inside your *.bat script?

Comment: I've contemplated doing that (it would be a LOT less complicated) but a .vbs script is a lot more user friendly.

Answer (score 0):

Your VBScript can be as simple as this:

```
WScript.Quit MsgBox("Would you like to install the AntrixAPI?", vbYesNo, "Installing AntrixAPI")
```

Call it from your batch file and test the return value. `vbYes` has a value of 6, `vbNo` has a value of 7.

```
@echo off
cscript c:\test.vbs

if %errorlevel%==6 goto UserSelectedYes
if %errorlevel%==7 goto UserSelectedNo
```

Comment: Giving this a test currently. I'll see how it goes.
EDIT: Using this, it opens up a CMD window (in the correct directory) but it doesn't execute the command I've set under the label. It just opens the CMD window waiting for the user to input a command

Comment: I've put this in the `call test.vbs` that I have and what it does is give me some sort of error and then opens another CMD window waiting for the user to execute a command.

Comment: Are you trying to return back to your original batch file? Or launch a new one?

Comment: Return to the original file. But it's OK, I've found the solution.

Comment: OK, good. I just updated mine to show how you can return to the original.

Answer (score 0):

This is how to download a file in vbscript.

```
 On Error Resume Next
 Set File = WScript.CreateObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP")
 File.Open "GET", "http://www.pepperresources.org/LinkClick.aspx?fileticket=B1doLYYSaeY=&tabid=61", False
 'This is IE 8 headers
 File.setRequestHeader "User-Agent", "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 8.0; Windows NT 6.0; Trident/4.0; SLCC1; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; Media Center PC 5.0; .NET CLR 1.1.4322; .NET CLR 3.5.30729; .NET CLR 3.0.30618; .NET4.0C; .NET4.0E; BCD2000; BCD2000)"
 File.Send
 If err.number <> 0 then 
    line =""
    Line  = Line &  vbcrlf & "" 
    Line  = Line &  vbcrlf & "Error getting file" 
    Line  = Line &  vbcrlf & "==================" 
    Line  = Line &  vbcrlf & "" 
    Line  = Line &  vbcrlf & "Error " & err.number & "(0x" & hex(err.number) & ") " & err.description 
    Line  = Line &  vbcrlf & "Source " & err.source 
    Line  = Line &  vbcrlf & "" 
    Line  = Line &  vbcrlf & "HTTP Error " & File.Status & " " & File.StatusText
    Line  = Line &  vbcrlf &  File.getAllResponseHeaders
    wscript.echo Line
    Err.clear
    wscript.quit
 End If

On Error Goto 0

 Set BS = CreateObject("ADODB.Stream")
 BS.type = 1
 BS.open
 BS.Write File.ResponseBody
 BS.SaveToFile "c:\users\test.txt", 2
```

Comment: This isn't really what I wanted. I only want the user to be prompted using a VBS because of the popup box. I really want all of the functions to be done in the CMD window.

Comment: `choice /c yn /m "Install ABC"` `if errorlevel 1 wget "http://etc"` `if errorlevel 2 goto :eof`