# Batch file conditional depending on user response to VBScript MsgBox

Tags: batch-file, vbscript

I know how to create a MsgBox with .vbs and how to start them with a batch file.

How do I write a conditional in the batch file, such that the flow of execution will depend on which MsgBox button the user clicks?

Comment: Did you mean hitting cancel on the MSGBOX ?
Can you post your code ?

Comment: Maybe [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21575421/2861476) can help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Test.vbs :**

```
msgbox("Question",vbyesno,"Title")
```

**Test.bat :**

```
for /f "tokens=*" %%a in ('cscript //nologo test.vbs') do (
set results=%%a
)

if "%results%"=="6" (echo do something) else (echo do another thing)
pause
```